# Table will not render in Shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I have been messing with making a shiny app and I feel as though i am doing everything in the correct manner to get the table to render but no luck. In my app you should you upload an csv and then go to the data frame tab. I have tried many small changes but nothing seems to work. Id imagine this has something to do with the server section but i cant see it.

R ui:

```
library(readxl)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(readr)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)
library(DT)
library(xtable)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("slate"), mainPanel(
  navbarPage(
    "Permian Plots", collapsible = TRUE, fluid = TRUE,
    navbarMenu(
      "County Plot",
      tabPanel( 
        sidebarPanel( fileInput(
          'file1',
          'Choose CSV File',
          accept = c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv')
        ),
        tags$hr(),
        checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
        # App buttons comma and quote
        radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                     c(
                       Comma = ',',
                       Semicolon = ';',
                       Tab = '\t'
                     ), ','),
        radioButtons(
          'quote',
          'Quote',
          c(
            None = '',
            'Double Quote' = '"',
            'Single Quote' = "'"
          ),
          '"'
        ))
      ),

      tabPanel("Data Frame",
               fluidRow(box(DT::dataTableOutput("contents")))),

      tabPanel("County Plot", plotlyOutput(
        "plotMap", height = 1200, width = 1200
      ),
      actionButton("btn", "Plot")
               )
    )
  )
)

)
```

Server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 200*1024^2) 

  dsnames <- c()

  data_set <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile)){
      return()
    }

    data_set <- read.csv(
      inFile$datapath,
      header = input$header,
      sep = input$sep,
      quote = input$quote

    )
  })

  output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
    withProgress(message = 'loading...', value = 0.1, {

      datatable(data_set(), 
                options = list(
        "pageLength" = 40))
      extensions = 'Responsive' 
      setProgress(1)

    })

  })

  output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
    selectInput("dataset", "Data set", as.list(data_sets))
  })


  observeEvent(
    input$btn,
    {
      output$plotMap <- renderPlotly({withProgress(message = 'Plotting...', value = 0.1,{
        plot <- Plots(data_set(),
                      "Martin County", 
                      "~/Work/permin/martin county/martin data/f1.csv",
                      "~/Work/permin/BestMartinPlotSat.html",
                      32.1511, -101.5715)
        setProgress(1)

      })

      })
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Function:
Should not be the problem causer in this.

```
Plots <- function(df, C_name, PathCSV, PathWidg, Lat, Lon){

  f1 <- df

  f1$Date <- as.POSIXct(f1$Date)

  f1$year <- format(as.POSIXct(f1$Date,format="%y-%m-%d"), "%y")
  f1$month <- format(as.POSIXct(f1$Date,format="%y-%m-%d"), "%m")

  f1$Cell <- as.factor(f1$Cell)

  z <- ddply(f1, c("year", "month", "Cell"), summarise,
             yearMonth_Max_sum = max(`Cell Sum (Norm)`))

  f1 <- inner_join(f1,z, by = c("year", "month", "Cell"))


  f1$Changed <- as.numeric(as.factor(f1$Changed))
  f1$Changed[f1$Changed == 1] <- 0
  f1$Changed[f1$Changed == 2] <- 1

  z <- ddply(f1, c("year", "month", "Cell"), summarise,
             ChangedX = max(Changed))

  f1 <- inner_join(f1,z, by = c("year", "month", "Cell"))

  f1$MY <- paste(f1$year, f1$month, sep = "-")

  #preapring data for plotly

  q <- matrix(quantile(f1$StdDev))

  f1$qunat <- NA

  up <- matrix(quantile(f1$StdDev, probs = .95))

  up

  f1$qunat <- ifelse((f1$StdDev > q[4:4,1]) & (f1$StdDev < up[1,1]), 1, 0)

  z <- group_by(f1, Cell) %>%
    summarize(Median_Cell = median(`Cell Sum (Norm)`, na.rm = FALSE))

  f1 <- inner_join(f1,z, by = c("Cell"))

  quantile(round(f1$Median_Cell))

  f1$NewMedian <- NA
  f1$NewMedian[f1$Median_Cell > 4000] <- 0
  f1$NewMedian[f1$Median_Cell <= 4000] <- 1

  f1$NewSum <- NA
  f1$NewSum <- f1$yearMonth_Max_sum * f1$ChangedX * f1$qunat * f1$NewMedian

  write_csv(f1, PathCSV )

  f2 <- f1[!duplicated(f1$yearMonth_Max_sum), ]

  #plolty plot

  Sys.setenv('MAPBOX_TOKEN' = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiY3dvb2RzMjIiLCJhIjoiY2prMnlycmduMDJvNjNxdDEzczNjdGt3YSJ9.RNuCSlHyKZpkTQ8mJmg4aw')

  p <- f2[which(f2$yearMonth_Max_sum < 9000),] %>%
    plot_mapbox(
      lon = ~Lon, 
      lat = ~Lat, 
      size = ~yearMonth_Max_sum,
      color = ~(NewSum), 
      frame = ~MY, 
      type = 'scattermapbox',
      mode = 'markers',
      colors = c("green","blue")
    ) %>%
    add_markers(text = ~paste("Sum", yearMonth_Max_sum, "/<br>", 
                              "Standard Dev", StdDev, "/<br>", 
                              "Mean", Average, "/<br>", 
                              "Median", Median_Cell, "/<br>",
                              "Changed", ChangedX, "/<br>", 
                              "Latitude", Lat , "/<br>", 
                              "Longitude", Lon)) %>%
    layout(title = C_name,
           font = list(color = "black"),
           mapbox = list(style = "satellite", zoom = 9,
                         center = list(lat = Lat,
                                       lon = Lon)))


  p
  htmlwidgets::saveWidget(p, PathWidg)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the last thing in your function is what is returned. you are returning `setprogress(1)` to `renderdatatable()`

```
 output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
    withProgress(message = 'loading...', value = 0.1, {

      datatable(data_set(), 
                options = list(
        "pageLength" = 40))
      extensions = 'Responsive' 
      setProgress(1)

    })
```

Try this instead

```
 output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
    withProgress(message = 'loading...', value = 0.1, {

     datatab <- datatable(data_set(), 
                options = list(
        "pageLength" = 40))
      extensions = 'Responsive' 
      setProgress(1)
     datatab

    })
```